How to Identify Which Browser Tab or Window Triggered an Event in Angular?
I'm working on an Angular-based web application that tracks user events. The app can be opened in multiple browser tabs or windows simultaneously, and we want to identify which specific tab or window triggered an event.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Track events in the app that users trigger across multiple tabs or windows.
Assign a unique identifier (ID) to each tab or window instance.
Determine, based on this ID, from which tab or window an event originated.



Every time the user opens your app, generate a unique ID and add it as a query param in the URL.
Any time a request is made from the app, fetch the unique ID from the query param.
Reference the ID and match it against the query param to confirm which tab made the request.

You can't use cookies or local storage, because those are shared across tabs. Each browser tab can have a unique URL however, so this is the perfect opportunity to persist a unique ID.

Can we use sessionStorage here? Since each tab or window has its own sessionStorage that persists until the tab or window is closed (and retains data through page reloads) we can store a unique ID in the sessionStorage when the user opens the app. Then, before any requests we can get the ID from the sessionStorage. This approach also avoids adding an ID to the URL.

Sure! That would also work. Duplicating a tab copies the tab's sessionStorage into the new tab, but that is no different than doing the same with the URL.

Interesting, I was unaware that duplicating a tab also duplicates its sessionStorage.

I would suggest using the broadcastChannel API for this. Each time app.component initialises (in each new tab/window/iFrame) it would create a unique ID for itself and retain this as a local variable.
At the point you wish to emit an event from any tab/window you would simply pass the event through a broadcast service (providing the ID as part of the message) and all subscribers are notified and can perform any related application logic:
// broadcast.service.ts
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

export interface BroadcastMessage {
  tabId: string;
  data: any;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BroadcastService implements OnDestroy {
  private channel: BroadcastChannel;
  private messageSubject = new BehaviorSubject<BroadcastMessage>();
  public messages$ = this.messageSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    
    this.channel = new BroadcastChannel('app-communication');
    
    this.channel.onmessage = (event) => {
      const message: BroadcastMessage = event.data;    
        this.messageSubject.next(message);      
    };
  }

  send(tabId: string, data: any): void {
    this.channel.postMessage({
      tabId,
      data
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.channel.close();
    this.messageSubject.complete();
  }
}

